# Chrome - Hiding scrolled content causing body and other elements to scroll up

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, scroll

I am dividing my webpage in two vertical parts. Where left panel is used to render a list of categories of books and right panel is used for rendering books associated with selected category. We also have buttons to hide a specific category from left side.

```
<div class="content">
  <div class='col-3'> 
    <h3> Category </h3>
    <div class="category-container dev-category-list">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='col-9'> 
    <h3> Books </h3>
    <div class="books-container dev-books-list">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript Code:

```
var categories = ['category-1','category-2','category-3','category-4','category-5','category-6','category-7'];
var books = {'cat1':['1984','Dracula','Twilight','Holes','Homes','Uglies','Othello'],'cat2':['Dracula','Twilight','1984','Holes','Homes','Uglies','Othello'],'cat3':['1984','Twilight','Holes','Homes','Dracula','Uglies','Othello'],'cat4':['Othello','1984','Dracula','Uglies','Holes','Twilight','Eclipse'],'cat5':['Hamlet','Macbeth','Othello','Holes','Night','Twilight','Eclipse'],'cat6':['1984','Hamlet','Dracula','Uglies','Othello','Night','Twilight'],'cat7':['1984','Hamlet','Macbeth','Uglies','Othello','Holes','Night']};

setup_UI_elements();

function setup_UI_elements(){
  appendCategories();
  renderBooks('1');
  addCategListner();
  addBtnListner();
}

function appendCategories(){
    container = $('.dev-category-list');
   for(var i=0; i< categories.length; i++){
     categHtml = "<div data-categ-id='"+ (i+1) + "' class='categ'> "+categories[i]+" </div>";
     container.append(categHtml)
   }
}

function renderBooks(categ_id){
   container = $('.dev-books-list');
   container.html('');
   categ_key = 'cat'+categ_id
   $('.categ').removeClass('selected');
   $('div.categ[data-categ-id='+categ_id+']').addClass('selected');
   for(var i=0; i< books[categ_key].length; i++){
     bookHTML = "<div data-book-id='"+ (i+1) + "' class='book'> "+books[categ_key][i];
     bookHTML += "<button type='button' data-book-id='"+ (i+1) + "' data-categ-id='"+ (books[categ_key].length-i) + "' class='btn'> Hide Categ "+ (books[categ_key].length-i) +"</button> </div>";
     container.append(bookHTML);
   }
}

function addCategListner(){
  container = $('.dev-category-list');
  container.click(function(e){
    target = $(e.target);
    $('.categ').removeClass('selected hidden');
    target.toggleClass('selected');
    categ_id = target.data('categ-id');
    renderBooks(categ_id);      
  });
}

function addBtnListner(){
  container = $('.dev-books-list');
  container.click(function(e){
    target = $(e.target);
    if(target.hasClass('btn')){
      categ_id = target.data('categ-id');
      target.toggleClass('added');
      if(target.hasClass('added'))
        target.html('Show Categ'+categ_id)
      else
        target.html('Hide Categ'+categ_id)

        categDiv = $('.dev-category-list div[data-categ-id='+categ_id+']')
      categDiv.toggleClass('hidden');
    }
  });

}
```

When I try to hide a category from left panel which is no longer in above the fold then it is scrolling right panel instead of left panel.

I works fine in Firefox and Safari.

JS Bin: https://jsbin.com/bafasoy/edit?html,js,output

Comment: This works well for me !

Comment: try to click on last button in the right side, you will see right panel is scrolling. I checked with windows/ mac chrome browser.

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome : 58.0.3029.110 for Mac.

Comment: I tested on chrome, firefox and opera and no scrolling happens but there is a scroll bar.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: For Chrome as soon as 2nd category goes above the screen, click on 'Hide Categ 2' button you will see that button will move down. I checked with Windows/MacBook. Which version are you using?

Comment: Version 55.0.2883.87 (64-bit)

Comment: Actually I checked with 3-4 other Windows and Mac users, same issue.